# How to fix "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule"

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I'm trying to run an Angular application using webpack but keep getting this error in the browser console during app startup (seems to come from compiler.js):

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)
```

I started my solution using the Angular CLI, then added a custom webpack configuration. I have done a lot of reading, searching, tweaking and trial and error, but am still not sure where the problem is. It could be with the dev server, my webpack configuration, babel, or potentially something like core-js or some issue with the dependencies I am using.

I run the app using:

```
webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js
```

Below are the files I thought were most important to share. I'm thinking my webpack config is possibly where the issue lies, but I'm not sure.

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myapp';
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]    
  }
}
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
});
```

webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;


module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],

                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                modules: false
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },

                test: /\.js$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },          
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'to-string-loader',
                    { 
                        loader: 'css-loader', 
                        options: { 
                            sourceMap: true 
                        } 
                    },
                    { 
                        loader: 'sass-loader', 
                        options: { 
                            sourceMap: true 
                        } 
                    }
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
            }
        ]
    },

    entry: {
        app: './src/main.ts',
        vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
        styles: './src/assets/app-theme.scss'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    priority: -10,
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            },

            chunks: 'all',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 30000,
            name: true
        },
        minimizer: [new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
        noEmitOnErrors: true

    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'MyApp',
            template: './src/indexTemplate.html',
            inject: 'body',
            favicon: './src/favicon.ico',
            meta: { viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        }),

    ]
};
```

polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/promise';

import 'classlist.js'; 

import 'core-js/es/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';  
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~11.13.5",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: try to adding: ```import 'core-js/es7/reflect';```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5xs2qx?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts

Comment: thanks @mojtabaramezani but doesn't core-js 3 use core-js/es/reflect instead, and I'm already importing that in the polyfill file?

Comment: Would it be hard to create a plunkr for this?

Comment: I have the same issue, disabeling the HtmlWebpackPlugin removes this issue for me (but then i do not have my template replacements). Internet claims it's a circular dependency. I never had the issue with webpack watch, am currently migrating to ng serve (thus dev-server) and it goes there indeed, and if you disable constructors or remove includes it drops down further down the lane eventuallly ending up in ApplicationModule